# RxJava: Know when observable is finished and return Boolean Observable to the caller

Tags: android, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android, rx-java2

I am new to RxJava. My experience is mainly from those tutorials:
[Here](https://www.toptal.com/android/functional-reactive-android-rxjava), and [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/wiki).

Now, I found myself in a situation where I have API call with Retrofit2 that will return an `Obesrvable<AccessToken>`. The client will call this service as follows:

```
public Observable<TokenResult> authenticateWithClientCredentials() {
        return authService.authenticate("client_credentials").take(1);
}
```

Where a class called `Authenticator` will call `#authenticateWithClientCredentials()` from the client.

What I would like to achieve is to return an `Observable<Boolean>` from the `Authenticator` class, once the API call is finished, i.e. inside `onComplete()` to indicate that the access token has been fetched and saved in cache inside the `Authenticator` class successfully.

I tried the `defer` operator but I'm still lost.

**EDIT**

I know I can pass a callback in the parameters, but isn't the idea of Rx to replace the old classic callbacks approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, then this is what you are searching:

```
    client.authenticateWithClientCredentials()
          .map(token -> {
              // save `token` into cache
              return token;
          })
          .flatMap(integer -> Observable.just(Boolean.TRUE))
          .subscribe(aBoolean -> {
              // success
          }, throwable -> {
              // error
          });
```

I do not know why exactly you want `Observable<Boolean>`, Completable is much more preferred in this case, because either the stream has successfully completed or no. Nevertheless, posted the solution using `Observable<Boolean>` return type.

Here's the `Completable` approach:

```
    client.authenticateWithClientCredentials()
          .flatMapCompletable(integer -> {
              // save `token` into cache
              return Completable.complete();
          })
          .subscribe(() -> {
              // success
          }, throwable -> {
              // error
          });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but not quite what I wanted.
#authenticateWithClientCredentials is not a method in the Authenticator class, it is a method in the Client class. The Authenticator will call authenticateWithClientCredentials and cache the token, after that I want the Authenticator to return an Observable<Boolean> to indicate that the token was successfully set in cache.

Comment: Can you please explain to me what is (and why) Completable is more preferred?

Comment: `Completable` represents a stream, which either completes or fails (i.e. only `onComplete()` and `onError()` methods exist). In your case it is logical, that either that action (the action that  you are performing) completes, or it terminates with error. Obviously, it is not an infinite stream of booleans, which `Observable<Boolean>` represents.

Comment: I would really appreciate it when you can add another solution with Completable. Thanks in advance